# AVPlayer seekToTime

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, avplayer

I am using a periodicTimeObserverForInterval to update a plot to reflect my current audio waveform. This works great and has been giving me no trouble. It stays in sync with pausing and starting. However, when I tried to introduce arbitrary seeking into my code, the waveform visual becomes out of sync with the playing audio. This doesn't make sense to me unless the time sent to my observer is wrong after calling the seek function.

```
            // timeScale = 22050 = sampleRate
            let timeScale = self.player.currentItem.asset.duration.timescale;

            self.player.seekToTime(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(time), timeScale), toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler: {
                (Bool) -> Void in
                self.player.play();
            });
```

I can't figure out why this function is causing the visual to get out of sync.

Comment: Can't see how the above would affect things. Is your observer self contained? Is it using the player's current time as a sample point or are you passing round a variable? Does it settle down after a while?

Comment: I was using the time argument provided to the observer block. Using audacity I verified a certain segment of audio begins at 75s. When I seek to this position in time, the waveform appears correctly at 75s. However, the audio does not begin playing for another 2 seconds.

Comment: So does the player's current time match the time argument provided to the block? It's a while since I worked on low level compressed audio but I'd imagine it's similar to video which needs a keyframe every now and then. Reading a constant stream of audio is easy as your data is just relative to what came before. When you skip to a new position it would take a while to reconstruct the baseline.

Comment: It does. Ultimately I switched over to EZAudio, which uses AudioComponents for playback and ExtFileServices for seeking. I have no idea what was wrong with AVPlayer.